# Kubernetes set environment variables depending on namespace

Tags: configuration, namespaces, kubernetes

I want to set specific env variables depending on the namespace.

The goal is to have one config yaml file for different namespaces and set different env variables/config maps for dev, qa and prod depending on the namespace which the config file is applied to.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, kubernetes doesn't come with this capability out of the box.

There are two ways to get around this:

1. Deploy a standard ConfigMap that contains everything any deployment needs. Make your app recognise the namespace and use the appropriate variable.
2. Deploy a sidecar app that generates a namespace-specific ConfigMap from a template. This sidecar will need access to kube-apiserver to deploy new ConfigMap manifests automatically.